# excel, filter on, shift column values to the left

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a filter on. I need to shift column values to the left. Please see below screenshot.

In below screenshot, I want to delete Name1 - Name5 and shift all the cells on the right to the left. I can't do this. Excel will not let me. It wants me to delete the entire row which I do not want to do.

I also do not want to use the = next column formula since there are 50+ columns in this spreadsheet. So I need some help and advice.

I have tried to highlight the first Home to Address5 and drag that to the left, then get error message

```
The command you chose cannot be performed with multiple selections. Select a single range and click the command again.
```

[image]

Comment: Can you redo the screenshot to include the row numbers?  Hidden/non-visible rows when filtering are significant to this.

Comment: I just did that. Please see screenshot. I have no idea how to attach on here, maybe you can't but I do have sample data.

Comment: If it's a continuous range, you should not have any issues. As Cyril has mentioned, we may be dealing with hidden rows/columns here. It would be easier, if you add the row and column headers to the screenshot

Comment: Yes I added the row numbers. Please see the current screenshot

Comment: Please see updated screenshot.